# How to install a Python Recipe File (.py)?

Tags: python, installation, python-3.x, recipe

I'm new to Python. I'm currently on Py3k (Win).

I'm having trouble installing a `.py` file. Basically, i want to use the recipes provided at the bottom of [this](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/itertools.html) page. So i want to put them inside a `.py` and `import` them in *any* of my source codes.

So i copied all the recipes into a `recipes.py` file and copied them to `C:\Python3k\Lib\site-packages`.

Now, the `import` works fine, but when i try to call any function (eg. `take`) from it, i got a `global name 'islice' is not defined`...So i figured, i should add an `itertools` import to `recipes.py`

I still get the same error? Do i need to change all instances to `itertools.<funcname>`? how can i make the import's global? Is this a new Py3k change? Is there something i missing?

Thanks in advance, :)

Comment: did you use `from itertools import *` in `recipes.py`?

Comment: @jcubic, `global name 'itertools' is not defined` for `recipes.py`? :-\ Odd!

Comment: You should ask, how to install python module (I'm sure there is lot of info).

Comment: @alxx, this has nothing to do with installing a module. @jcubic. please stick to graphic design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two closely-related issues.

First, *within* recipes.py, you need access to all of itertools.

At the very least, this means you need

```
import itertools
```

at the top. But in this case you would need to qualify all of the itertools functions as `itertools.<funcname>`, as you say. (You could also use `import itertools as it` and then `it.<funcname>`.)

Second, you could do

```
from itertools import islice, count, chain
```

but you would need to put all of the needed functions in the list.

Finally, the least recommended, but probably easiest, is to do

```
from itertools import *
```

This is dangerous because it pollutes your namespace with *everything* from `itertools`, which is considered bad and uncontrolled, but in this case probably isn't terrible.

*Second*, you have a similar problem in all of your code that *uses* `recipes.py`; you'll need to qualify or explicitly import everything. So, either

```
import recipes
recipes.take(...)
```

or

```
from recipes import take
take(...)
```

Comment: +1 but I honestly wouldn't even mention `from foo import *`. look at jcubic's comment on the question for proof that we're not _all_ adults.

Comment: I know `from blah import *` is frowned upon, but this is strictly for solving project euler and stuff...so it doesn't really matter for me,in this case anyway... :)

Comment: `from itertools import *` is the appropriate import statement here. If future recipes are added, they may use new itertools functions which would need to be added to an explicit import. The recipe definitions expect to be run from within the itertools namespace. You don't need to worry about polluting the module namespace, since this is precisely the namespace you *want* for the recipes module. (A case like this, where you're "extending" another module, is one of the prime use cases for a wildcard import.)